# Can multiple joins exist in a single sql statement

Tags: derby

A good example of this would be

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE M LEFT OUTER JOIN N, P LEFT OUTER JOIN Q..
```

Comment: Yes, if [ANSI SQL Compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance) is claimed. Derby features are [listed here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DERBY/SQLvsDerbyFeatures).

Comment: Add it as the answer. I’ll accept it. Thanks for the link!